# Newly added web wildcard certificate shows as expired

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis

I have a web wildcard certificate on our web server that runs on IIS 7.5 using Windows 2008 R2. The CMS is Drupal Acquia 7. The certificate expired last month, so we imported the new .PFX file certificate in IIS.
When loading up the web page, the user keeps getting presented with the certificate date expired error (On Chrome: NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID). I deleted the old wildcard certificate on IIS and also in the Certificate Console of the server, but still get presented with the date expired error.

I have checked that the new imported  certificate expires next year. I tried searching everywhere in the certificate console and deleted all the instances of the expired certificate, but still get the same error.

Comment: The same wildcard certificate was installed on the Exchange server without a hitch. The time is syncing correctly. When viewing the certificate in the console (Under Personal and Enterprise Trust), it says it is ok.

Comment: Same on all browsers.

Comment: The web server doesn't have an anti virus.

Comment: No AV on the client as well. Same on mobile. When I look in the client side, I see the certificate date period of the old deleted certificate.

Comment: May I suggest that maybe you haven't deleted it, and/or bound the replacement to the service correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/Article/View/682/35/) site that mentions about binding the certificate to the https 443 port and with the detailed instructions found [here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO22115.html).